# Multiply n number of NumPy samples by a single sample and sum the output along axis=1

Tags: numpy

Let's say I have an numpy array (10, 5) which is 10 samples with 5 features. How can I multiply the entire array by a single sample (1, 5), and sum the output row-wise such that my output is (10,1) and I have a single value for each sample.

Comment: Isn't this just a matrix vector multiplication? What about `A @ b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# Create your (10, 5) array (10 samples with 5 features)
array_10x5 = np.random.rand(10, 5)

# Create your single sample (1, 5)
single_sample = np.random.rand(1, 5)

# Multiply the entire (10, 5) array with the single sample using broadcasting
result = np.sum(array_10x5 * single_sample, axis=1)

# result is now a (10,) array where each element corresponds to the sum of the 
element-wise products
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.rand(10, 5)

a2 = np.random.rand(1, 5)

result = np.zeros((10, 1))
print(result)

product = a1 * a2
print(product)

for i in range(len(product)):
    result[i] = np.sum(product[i])

print(result)
```

I wrote this code based on what I understood from what you are saying. Is this the output you want?